# iPad issue when writing in edit and question forms

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, ipad

When I type into edit or question forms like the one I am typing in now my screen jumps to the top of the screen for every character I write. Usually not a big deal for questions as you can see what you write when you are already at top, but very annoying for editing as that requires you too scroll down in order to see what you write.

**Edit**: This happens on superuser.com aswell

Comment: Does it occur on other stackexchange sites?

Comment: I have just tried it on [security.se], on [metase], and on [su], and I can't reproduce it anywhere with an iPad 2. Can you describe in a little more detail what you're doing and what happens?

Comment: @Balpha, when I for example want to answer a question I have to scroll down into the text-field where I can put my answer in. Once I start typing into the field, every character I type takes my view all the way back to the top of the page. That way I have to scroll down again to see if I typed correctly. Maybe it is a javascript event that bugs out on my iPad or something (iPad 1). It does not happend in comment fields, only question and answer fields. I use jailbroken iPad with IOS 3.2.2. Have not patched in a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't support such old versions of iOS. I'm afraid you'll need to upgrade to fix this "bug" of ours :)